# League Of Legends fps drops

Tags: league-of-legends

I have the fps issues, when I did play in the last patch it did work fine, but this patch seems to ruin everything! I did play on high graphics and had shadows and anything at high, now I play on low graphics did turn shadows off but still got the problem, I normally have 60 fps when i play but 4-6 times in a game it drops down to 5-6 fps then it last in 2-3 mins and it goes up again to 60 fps.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Im not sure, that`s why i ask here. Hoping to get some answeres. Impossible to play like this

Comment: Did the answers on the other question not solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reinstalling? I had the same issue and I reinstalled. I also downloaded Razer Game Booster which made every game 60 fps.